# laravel eloquent left join not outputting

Tags: laravel-4, left-join, eloquent

I'm trying to achieve this

```
SELECT *
FROM pending
LEFT JOIN users ON pending.user_id = users.id
WHERE pending.school_id = '1'
```

Which produces two results of the two tables combined with the users details output.

Pending Model

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
public function school(){
    return $this->belongsTo('School');
}
```

User model

```
public function pending(){
    return $this->hasMany('Pending','user_id');
}
```

School Model

```
public function pending(){
    return $this->hasMany('Pending','school_id');
}
```

Controller

```
$pending_user = Pending::with('users')->where('school_id', '=', '1')->get();
```

This retrieves an array of the two records but a null result in the user array.

```
"users":null
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go with this

```
$pending_user = Pending::select('first_name','last_name','user_id','how')->where('school_id', '=', '1')->leftjoin('users','pending.user_id','=','users.id')->get();
```